# pytest, parametrize x in first list and y in second list

Tags: python, automation, pytest, parametrized-testing

```
xlist = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
ylist = ["xp1", "xp2", "xp3"]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("url, xp", [(xlist, ylist)])
class Test01:
    def test_001(self, url, xp):
        print(url)
        print(xp)
```

**Result**:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
PASSED                            
[100%]['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
['xp1', 'xp2', 'xp3']
```

**Target result:**

```
PASSED                                [ 33%]url1 xp1
PASSED                                [ 66%]url2 xp2
PASSED                                [100%]url3 xp3
```

For one list it works with "@pytest.mark.parametrize("url", xlist)", but I didn't find something about multiple. Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("url, xp", zip(xlist, ylist))
class Test01:
    def test_001(self, url, xp):
        print(url)
        print(xp)
```

I've looked for this.